# Continuously generate a multiple element vector for addition

Tags: r, vector, addition

When `X` contains one element I run my procedure like this

```
set.seed(333)
X <- numeric()
Y <- matrix(0, 4, 4)

for (j in 1:4) {
  for (i in 1:4) {       
    if (j == 1) {
      X[i] <- c(sample(10, 1))
      Y[j, i] <- 2*X[i]
    } else {
      X[i] <- c(sample(10, 1))
      Y[j, i] <- 5*Y[j - 1, i] + X[i]
    }
  }
}
Y
```

My problem is how to get `Y` when my `X` contains 2 elements now generated with `c(sample(10, 1), sample(10, 1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about handle it with arrays?

```
set.seed(333)
X <- array(0, c(4,2))
Y <- array(0, c(4, 4, 2))

for (j in 1:4) {
  for (i in 1:4) {       
    
    X[i, 1:2] <- sample(10, 2, replace = TRUE)
    
    if (j == 1)  Y[j, i, 1:2] <- 2*X[i, 1:2]
    else         Y[j, i, 1:2] <- 5*Y[j - 1, i, 1:2] + X[i, 1:2]
    
  }
}

Y
#> , , 1
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]   18    4    4    6
#> [2,]   97   21   30   34
#> [3,]  494  108  156  171
#> [4,] 2475  550  781  858
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]   14   14   12   14
#> [2,]   78   77   66   76
#> [3,]  396  391  333  390
#> [4,] 1990 1959 1670 1959
```

Notice that here you have the couples you were looking for:

```
Y[1,1,]
#> [1] 18 14
Y[1,2,]
#> [1]  4 14
Y[1,3,]
#> [1]  4 12
Y[1,4,]
#> [1]  6 14

Y[2,1,]
#> [1] 97 78
Y[2,2,]
#> [1] 21 77
Y[2,3,]
#> [1] 30 66
Y[2,4,]
#> [1] 34 76

Y[3,1,]
#> [1] 494 396
Y[3,2,]
#> [1] 108 391
Y[3,3,]
#> [1] 156 333
Y[3,4,]
#> [1] 171 390

Y[4,1,]
#> [1] 2475 1990
Y[4,2,]
#> [1]  550 1959
Y[4,3,]
#> [1]  781 1670
Y[4,4,]
#> [1]  858 1959
```

I took out X from the if-else since you wouldn't have done it either way.

Also: `sample(10, 2, replace = TRUE)` is equivalent to `c(sample(10, 1), sample(10, 1))`, but it's shorter.

Comment: I want to generate 4 different vectors of X which contains 2 elements each and use them to obtain 4 different vectors of Y each time.Doing it manually, i want something like this example

`#  j=1,

#  X11=(7,8)    X12=(2,6)  X13=(1,9)   X14=(5,5)
#  Y11=(14,16)  Y12=(4,12) Y13=(2,18)  Y14=(10,10)

           #  j=2,
#  X21=(1,2)   X22=(2,3)    X23=(1,7)    X24=(3,9)
#  Y21=5*Y11+X21=(71,82)    Y22=5*Y12+X22=(22,63) 

`

Comment: Does Y have to be a matrix/array?

Comment: This does exactly what i needed. Thanks